# How to get hardhat to give more detailed error messages?

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, typescript

I am trying to call some function from the smart contract and I am only recieving the error message  `Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string` . This makes degubbing quite hard.
Is there some setting or dependency that I am missing?